# SQL Change Value + 10000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I Need help to change several values into a column in SQL, making an addition +10000 on the value actually inside the column. For example, the value in tPatSSlida of the first Name, in this case CLINIC DENT have to change from 0000000001 to 0000010001

Comment: You have to convert value into proper data type, which might be used for calculation, then you have to add leading zero's.

Comment: Please post code, not snapshots. By the way, you are posting sensitive data. I now know details about your database as well as information about some of your customers.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? BTW, I can't read that tiny image text...

Comment: @jarlh It is Microsoft SQL 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE TPatientRaw 
SET tPatSSlidaID = RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(CAST(tPatSSlida AS int) + 10000 AS VARCHAR), 10)
WHERE tPatSName = 'CLINIC DENT'
```

[simple test](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=abc03a39bbabd226e21cc98db21002f6)

Comment: It says Invalid object name 'tPatCulIntPatIDPk'.

Comment: *table name is `TPatientRaw`

Comment: @Radim Bača Doesn't work. Invalid object Name referred to the table 'TPatientRaw'

Comment: change the database where the `TPatientRaw` table is (don't be in master like in your screenshot)